# UIButton stop showing UIControl actions in interface builder after adding extension to it

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, interface-builder, protocol-extension

I have the simplest UI - just one button:[image]

As you can see, I can drag any event (like UITouchUpInside) from interface builder to my code.

BUT if I add some extension to UIButton like:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}

extension UIButton: SomeProtocol {}
```

those events no longer visible:
[image]

I'm using Xcode version 8.2 (8C38)

Can I somehow return them? Is it a bug in Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems an Xcode bug.

> A workaround you could try is to extend UIControl with the protocol.
>   UIControl is the superclass of UIButton, so extensions to UIControl
>   are inherited by UIButton, and Xcode doesn't seem to be upset when a
>   protocol is adopted by UIControl.

```
protocol SomeProtocol { }

extension UIControl: SomeProtocol { }
```

From Apple Developer Forums

[Adding a Swift protocol to UIButton breaks Interface Builder action options.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25180)